# Zend Framework 2 Checkbox setValue for unchecked not work

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-framework2

I tried set checkbox value in false:

```
$form->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
        'name' => 'test_checkbox',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Test checkbox',
            'use_hidden_element' => false,
            'checked_value' => 1,
            'unchecked_value' => 0,
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'value' => 0,
        ),
    ));
```

But as a result of this page contains:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox" value="1">
```

The value does not change and I can not understand why.

Other PHP and JS script not change this value.

Maybe I misunderstood how "checked_value", "unchecked_value" and "value" works?

Comment: Why are you setting `checked_value` and the `value` attribute to different things? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: value attribute can hold only on value at a time..

Comment: @TimFountain, checked_value and unchecked_value is alias for true and false (1 and 0). Value - must be default value for checkbox when page load.

Comment: @DCoder, can you explain?

Comment: @felixMind what you mean by this line Other PHP and JS script not change this value..?

Comment: @DCoder, this mean that only form generate value attribute.

Comment: you want to change value on checked or unchecked use jquery

Comment: @DCoder, not. I want to Zend set value by default in 0.

Comment: The unchecked value should appear in a hidden form field above the checkbox. It is not part of the checkbox element. Remove the attributes array from your checkbox definition as it does not do what you think it does. Ignore the comments about jquery.

Comment: @TimFountain, okay. But I still can't set value of visible checkbox to 0. And in this case how to work with chackbox value?

Comment: you can try like $form->get('test_checkbox')->setValue(0);

Comment: You said you want the checked value to be true (1), so why do you keep trying to set it to 0?

Comment: may be this can check or uncheck according to value try first

Comment: @DCoder, I have tried both approaches.

Comment: @TimFountain, I said I want value attribute in false (0) and checkbox in unchecked. Now I tried set checked_value in 0 and unchecked_value in 1,  in result checkbox have value = 0, but also have checked. It is not what I want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear which way you want it to work. If a user ticks the checkbox, what value do you want to be submitted? `1` or `0`?

Comment: @TimFountain, `1`. But when the page is loaded value must be `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have is almost correct. It should be:

```
$form->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox',
    'name' => 'test_checkbox',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Test checkbox',
        'use_hidden_element' => false,
        'checked_value' => 1,
        'unchecked_value' => 0,
    )
));
```

But I think you misunderstand how HTML checkboxes work. The value attribute should *always* contain *only* the checked value. Browsers only submit this value if the checkbox is ticked. So when the page loads, the checkbox will correctly appear in the source as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test_checkbox" value="1">
```

To achieve the unchecked value, ZF (and all other frameworks I know of) add it to a hidden form field *above* the checkbox. If the checkbox is not ticked, the browser will submit the hidden form field instead.